# Generating equidistant Points inside box which also contains MultiPolygon

Tags: python, point, geometry, shapely, point-in-polygon

I have a box bounded by `min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y`, I also have a multipolygon = poly contained in that box. I'm trying to equidistantly scatter points throughout that box, outside of that multipolygon, for the eventual purpose of using a modified A* algorithm to find a route between two points.
Right now, I can generate points as such:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
import numpy as np

x_range = np.linspace(min_y,max_y,round((max_y - min_y)*2.5),False)
y_range = np.linspace(min_x,max_x,round((max_x - min_x)*2.5),False)

points = []
point_dict = dict()
i = 0

for x in x_range:
    j = 0
    for y in y_range:
        p = Point(y,x)
        if not poly.contains(p):
            points.append(p)
            point_dict[i,j] = p
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

They're in an x-y grid along the map, but I think a more efficient/natural way to generate points for a path would be to create this grid then add a repulsion factor to each point so they're all pushed away from each other inversely proportional to their distance AND from the multipolygon and the bounding box. Eventually I imagine this would end up in some state equilibrium.

I stumbled upon the following question: [Electric force between particles using numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542603/electric-force-between-particles-using-numpy-arrays).

And was able to get an idea for how someone might approach this problem, but I'm still unsure how I could bound points to keep themm inside of a box and outside of the polygon/multipolygon that the box also contains.